# Second request from android-application to server return error 400 (bad request)

Tags: java, spring, rest

First request execute normally, but the same second request return error 400.
From browser this request execute full and normally many times.
Its very strange. Maybe, I dont understand AsyncTask .
This is request class:

```
private  class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    lgn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login) ;
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password) ;

    return template.getForObject(Constants.URL.HOST+"login?login="+lgn.getText()+"&pass="+pass.getText(), String.class);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
  String result = (str.substring(1,str.length()-1)).trim();
        TextView rView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resView);
        rView.setText(result);
        if (result.equals("user")){
            global gl  = (global) LoginActivity.this.getApplication();
            gl.setLogin(lgn.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UsersActionActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

}

logs error from android studio:

> 01-10 09:54:19.052 8119-8140/com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka W/RestTemplate: GET request for "http://192.168.1.47:8080/login/login=lox&password=1234" resulted in 400 (); invoking error handler
>   01-10 09:54:19.062 8119-8140/com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                               Process: com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka, PID: 8119
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>                                                                            Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 
>                                                                               at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
>                                                                               at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:585)
>                                                                               at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:541)
>                                                                               at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:499)
>                                                                               at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
>                                                                               at com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka.activities.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:45)
>                                                                               at com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka.activities.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:36)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

server code:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private AccountRepository accRep;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String loginQuery(@RequestParam (value ="login",required = true,defaultValue = "") String lgn,@RequestParam (value ="pass",required = true,defaultValue = "") String pass){
    String targetLogin = lgn.trim();
    String targetPass = pass.trim();

    String result = "none";

    List<Account> list = accRep.findAll();
    for (Account acc:list) {
        if (acc.getLogin().equals(targetLogin) && acc.getPassword().equals(targetPass)){
            result = acc.getAccountType();
        }
    }
    return  result;
}}
```

Comment: Irrespective of your question, consider re-designing the way you handle credentials and how authentication shall work. That isn't only insecure, but this is also not RESTful (as per your tagging).

Comment: Main challenge for me now - understand how to create request rightly

Comment: You typically design the resources (domain modelling), then you create your resource structures (URIs, and there is no such URI like "/api/login?... in REST), then you think about the HTTP methods you'll be using (GET, PUT, PATCH ...) and last the HTTP status codes (200, 201, 204, 400, 401, 404, ...). Do this first and you'll be happier in general. Good chance your issue disappears due to you having to rewrite the code anyway. Also, learn about Web authentication and how to do it properly. You may want to use request headers and go with standard approaches instead of inventing it yourself.